# Web base merge tool

Tags: git, merge, kdiff3

I'm looking for a solution to automatize merges between two branches, and I'd like to know if there are good web based merge client for manual merge (when conficts arise, human will still be better than the machine).

I use a lot kdiff3 and find it very well suited for quickly choose which branch needs to be used, and edit the result and save it. I'd like to have almost the same thing but in a web browser (with a server in python, or php, or java,...). I know kdiff3 has a pretty good automatic merge algorithm, I'm not asking for porting it completely of course :)

Thanks.
G.